# C Linux ioctl TCGETS and TCSETS errno 25

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

For an assignment, I am required to use ioctl, TCGETS and TCSETS.  I cannot use tcgetattr and tcsetattr.

Here's my code so far:

```
    struct termios term;
    int openLocation
    int ioResult
    openLocation = open("../../dev/fb0",O_RDWR);
    ioResult = ioctl(openLocation,TCGETS,&term);
```

This gets me errno 25.  I'm not really sure what the issue is.  I ultimately need to disable canonical mode by unsetting the ICANON bit and disabling ECHO, and, again, I need to use ioctl.  Thanks for your help guys

Comment: probably should make sure the open is succeeding

Comment: open definitely works

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/fb0` is a framebuffer device, not a terminal. You can't use `TCGETS` on it.

Do you perhaps mean `/dev/tty0`?

Comment: Interesting...well I definitely have to use fb0 for some of the visual stuff, but I guess that's not what I have to use to disable keypress echo...There isn't any mention of a file other than fb0 in the assignment, but perhaps tty0 is what I need to use...i'll give it a try, but is this something that would make sense given that i'm trying to disable key press echo?

Answer (score 1):

The addition of a perror or strerror would probably help you see that (as @kch mentioned) that your open call failed and the ioctl was being called on an invalid file (ENOTTY).